# Картинки не стают возле текста HTML

Tags: html

Картинки переносятся на другой ряд, а не становятся возле. Не могу понять почему. Длину сделал 100%, у блока `display: inline-block`, но что-то не выходит. 
P.S: картинки не продгружены , т.к. на ПК находятся, но там все равно понятно.

```css
.whatis {
  padding-left: 150px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 65px;
}

.textkneu {
  max-width: 400px;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'OpenSans-Bold';
  font-size: 25px;
}

p {
  font-family: 'OpenSans-Bold';
}

.imgpoc {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="whatis">
  <div class="textkneu">
    <h3>What is TEDxKNEU?</h3>
    <p> In the spirit of ideas worth spreading, TED has created a program called TEDx. TEDx is a program of local, self-organized events that bring people together to share a TED-like experience. Our event is called TEDxKNEU, where x = independently organized
      TED event. At our TEDxKNEU event, TEDTalks video and live speakers will combine to spark deep discussion and connection in a small group. The TED Conference provides general guidance for the TEDx program, but individual TEDx events, including ours,
      are self-organized.</p>
    <img class="imgpoc" src="./tedx-video-placeholder-bw.jpg">
  </div>
  <img class="imgpoc" src="./tedx-video-placeholder-bw.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: замени картинки теми что доступны в интернете, ничего не понятно.  где те свойства про которые ты пишешь?

Comment: display: inline-block где это в коде? или я ослеп уже

Comment: И приведите картинку или описание чего вы хотите, так как не очень понятно куда рядом вам нужно что бы она встала.

Comment: блин, 2к18 переходите на flex ;) дай классу "whatis" стили "display: flex; align-items: flex-start;" и будет тебе счастье

Answer (score 0):

если картинки должны быть рядом друг с другом, то вторую не нужно выносить за div.

```
<div class="whatis">
  <div class="textkneu">
    <h3>What is TEDxKNEU?</h3>
    <p> In the spirit of ideas worth spreading, TED has created a program called TEDx. TEDx is a program of local, self-organized events that bring people together to share a TED-like experience. Our event is called TEDxKNEU, where x = independently organized
      TED event. At our TEDxKNEU event, TEDTalks video and live speakers will combine to spark deep discussion and connection in a small group. The TED Conference provides general guidance for the TEDx program, but individual TEDx events, including ours,
      are self-organized.</p>
    <img class="imgpoc" src="./tedx-video-placeholder-bw.jpg">
    <img class="imgpoc" src="./tedx-video-placeholder-bw.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
  font-family: 'OpenSans-Bold';
  color: white;
}

.whatis {
  padding: 2px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.textkneu_2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 25px;
}

p {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="whatis">
  <div class="textkneu">
    <h3>What is TEDxKNEU?</h3>
    <div class="textkneu_2">
      <p> In the spirit of ideas worth spreading, TED has created a program called TEDx. TEDx is a program of local, self-organized events that bring people together to share a TED-like experience. Our event is called TEDxKNEU, where x = independently organized
        TED event. At our TEDxKNEU event, TEDTalks video and live speakers will combine to spark deep discussion and connection in a small group. The TED Conference provides general guidance for the TEDx program, but individual TEDx events, including
        ours, are self-organized.</p>
      <img class="imgpoc" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/245485/042ffebb-b671-40e4-9b01-fb815c942c58/s1200">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Хотел , что бы получилось вот так http://prntscr.com/in4cqk, но картинка не стает сбоку , а опускается вниз

Comment: Поможешь с проблемой?

Comment: С какой???????????

Comment: Хотел , что бы получилось вот так prntscr.com/in4cqk, но картинка не стает сбоку , а опускается вниз

Comment: Ну а в моем варианте ответа, что не так... Что не понятно?

Comment: У меня это не работает, так как надо

Comment: а что именно? объясни нормально, я же не ясновидящий...

Comment: У меня получается так , что картинка и текст тупо растянуты вниз. Они как бы стоят вместе , но не на всю ширину , а на процентов 20 , остальное вниз растянуто

Comment: Ну так что? Поможешь?

Comment: Как мне посмотреть, что да как ты делаешь?